# Using Delayed Paperclip With S3 Direct Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip, delayed-paperclip

I'm using Delayed Paperclip alongside direct uploads to S3. My model is called `Photo` and its attachment is `image`.

Images are uploaded to S3 using JavaScript from the Photo form. The file is stored in the location that Paperclip expects the original image to be located, and the file details are saved to hidden fields. When the form is submitted, these attributes are written to the Photo model:

`image_file_name
image_file_size
image_content_type`

Because writing these attributes alone doesn't seem to be enough to trigger Delayed Paperclip to process the image, after `Photo.save` I call `Photo.image.reprocess!` which does get DelayedPaperclip to create a new Sidekiq job which successfully processes the image.

The problem, is that when I call `Photo.save` in the `PhotosController`, the file is copied to a `temp` directory from S3, then back to S3. This happens outside of the job and is blocking:

```
[paperclip] copying image_assets/grab-original.tiff to local file /var/folders/bv/x495g9g10m7119680c9ssqmr0000gn/T/94943834d26bcb8b471f4eeb2a7f899d20141125-3895-1oqom7l
[AWS S3 200 2.601589 0 retries] get_object(:bucket_name=>"example-com-development",:key=>"image_assets/grab-original.tiff")

[paperclip] saving image_assets/grab-original.tiff
[AWS S3 200 2.47114 0 retries] put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"example-com-development",:cache_control=>"max-age=29030400",:content_length=>534472,:content_type=>"image/tiff",:data=>Paperclip::AttachmentAdapter: grab.tiff,:key=>"image_assets/grab-original.tiff")
```

**Why is Paperclip copying the file down and back again?**

Answer (score 0):

My approach was wonky.Even if it had worked it wouldn't have added the `image_processing` attribute to the `Photo` model.

After digging into the Delayed Paperclip API, the following seems to have done the trick:

Inside `PhotosController#create`:

```
# Ensure we are flagged as processing
@media_item.photo.prepare_enqueueing_for(:image)

if @media_item.save
   # Add Job
   @media_item.photo.enqueue_delayed_processing
end

respond_with(:admin, @galleryable, @media_item)
```

I have requested a better API here: https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/issues/116